# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while deploying the War in websphere which uses Couchbase cache

Tags: java, websphere, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I am facing the below error while deploying the war file in Websphere-8.5.5

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/params/SyncBasicHttpParams
        at com.couchbase.client.ViewConnection.createConnections(ViewConnection.java:120)
        at com.couchbase.client.ViewConnection.<init>(ViewConnection.java:100)
        at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnectionFactory.createViewConnection(CouchbaseConnectionFactory.java:184)
        at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.<init>(CouchbaseClient.java:247)
        at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.<init>(CouchbaseClient.java:179)
        at com.infosys.aham.services.utils.cache.CouchbaseCacheManager.instantiateCouchbaseManager(CouchbaseCacheManager.java:145)
        at com.infosys.aham.services.utils.cache.CouchbaseCacheManager.<init>(CouchbaseCacheManager.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        ... 87 more
```

I am using Couchbase-Client -1.1.9 and http-core-4.1.3
The http-core jar is bundled in the war file /web-inf/lib folder.

Also while looking in the websphere EnterprizeApplication-->*application* -->Manage Module --> *moduleName*--> ClassLoaderViewer --> LoaderView
 The http-core-4.1.3 is there in the table (jar is present in the classpath).
(I also tried with the http-core 4.1.1 jar.)

The application is still not able to find the class present in the given jar.
I am new to websphere, please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I sthe folder called "web-inf" or "WEB-INF"?  The name must be upper case.

Comment: NoClassDefFound menas that class was used in compilation but is not found at runtime so it's not in classloader at runtime. Try putting the http-core jar in lib folder of websphere.

Comment: Its in upper case "WEB-INF"

Comment: @ Fran Montero - can you specify where can i find the lib folder (in websphere). Also the jar is present in lib folder of WAR file, even then why is websphere not able to find the jar/class.

Comment: The http-core classes are already included in WebSphere, To use different implementation try to set Parent last in your web module, if it won't help you will need to create isolated shared library with conflicting libraries and map it to the application.

Comment: Thanks all for your responce. @Gas your suggestion of isolated shared library worked.

Comment: @user1516083 Added it as an answer, so you may accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http-core` classes are already included in WebSphere. To use different implementation create isolated shared library with conflicting libraries and map it to the application.